# Connecting an Oracle DB schema as a remote schema in postgres as a link

Tags: postgresql, oracle

In Oracle we can mount a remote oracle schema as a DB link. Is there a way to connect an Oracle schema to postgres similar to a DB link?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for Heterogeneous Connectivity (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11050/toc.htm)?  That allows you to create a database link in Oracle that connects to a non-Oracle database.  Or are you trying to go the other way and connect from the PostgreSQL database to the Oracle database?

Comment: Yes there is. In Postgres you can use `import foreign schema` from Oracle using [oracle_fdw](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw). See `foreign data`, the modern alternative of db-links [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html)